# SQL Server 2008 R2 creating trigger to check the data validation before execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

**The problem statement:** I need to change the data based on its value before getting the error of conversion.

For example: in my table `<MyTable>`, I have a column `Test1` and its type is `numeric`. The application generates a script to update data on that table.

In some cases, the data is wrongly set as 'NaN' and setting this value to `Test1` generates an error for obvious reasons. I want to create a trigger on that table so that data is set as 0 in cases of NaN. But the data validation is taking ahead of the execution of the trigger.

Is there any alternative approach for that?

Thanks and regards
Nilanjan Saha

Comment: So what is the problem? one  [`INSTEAD OF` trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) look perfect for this

Comment: First, I would handle that at the application level, Second, `NaN` means `Not a Number`. However, `0` is a number, and might be a valid value. I suggest changing `NaN` to `Null`.

Comment: We don't have control on the application, we only have control on the service part as well as the database part. The service is consumed by various applications and one of the application is passing wrong data, so we want to control that from database level.